# DatePickerDialog does not fit on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-datepicker

I'm developing wearable app. I used DatePickerDialog and not fit the screen. 
Does anyone have a solution?
This is my code:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog=new DatePickerDialog(this, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

        }
    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
    datePickerDialog.show();
```

Wear screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIXws.png

Comment: What code did you use? Explain your question in more detail.

Comment: DatePicker size could be changed if you have put it in layout.

Comment: Please add some own code, so we can see what you've already tried.

Comment: update my answer, I added my code

Comment: I'm trying simple DatePickerDialog on Android Wear.

Comment: Just don't use DatePickerDialog in a Wear app. It's not designed to fit on a 1" screen.

Comment: @alanv Okey but, I want to get date from user. How can i do this?

Comment: You would need to create your own custom view or find a library suitable for use on Wear.